# Get user that declared document as record CSOM

Tags: csom, 2016

Using CSOM is there anyway I can get the user that declared a document as record. I though I could use the **last modified** but it seems that when declaring a document as record **last modified** does not change.

Comment: It would be "Modified By" field which would hold the user's name. Additionally it's possible that you would need to dispose the `SPWeb` object you are referencing. This is a requirement to release a hold-status of the document which stays active after its declaration, thus actually finishing the update for the record's properties. Do you have it as part of your script?

Comment: Yes I do have it as part of a different client object context (I am using CSOM), and counter intuitively the Modified By does not change after record declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this via CSOM, only option is to roll out a web service with SOM that we can then consume on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's have look `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RecordsRepository.Records` DLL which does not contains any method to retrieve any property.

```
using System;

namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RecordsRepository
{
    [ScriptType("SP.RecordsRepository.Records", ServerTypeId = "{ea8e1356-5910-4e69-bc05-d0c30ed657fc}")]
    public static class Records
    {
        [Remote]
        public static void DeclareItemAsRecord(ClientRuntimeContext context, ListItem itemToDeclare);
        [Remote]
        public static void DeclareItemAsRecordWithDeclarationDate(ClientRuntimeContext context, ListItem itemToDeclare, DateTime declarationDate);
        [Remote]
        public static ClientResult<bool> IsRecord(ClientRuntimeContext context, ListItem item);
        [Remote]
        public static void UndeclareItemAsRecord(ClientRuntimeContext context, ListItem item);
    }
}
```

There is the just `IsRecord` method which has the boolean return type. Therefore not possible with CSOM using current `SharePoint.Client` DLL.

What possible solutions are,

> 1. you can write a `PowerShell script` which code mentioned below:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://content.contoso.com

$siteColl = $webApp.Sites

foreach ($site in $siteColl)

{

       $webs = $site.AllWebs

       foreach ($web in $webs)

       {

             $lists = $web.Lists

             foreach ($list in $lists)

             {

                    if ($list.BaseTemplate -eq "DocumentLibrary")

                    {

                           if (($list.Title -ne "List Template Gallery") -and ($list.Title -ne "Reporting Templates") -and ($list.Title -ne "Form Templates") -and ($list.Title -ne "Customized Reports") -and ($list.Title -ne "Site Assets") -and ($list.Title -ne "Style Library"))

                           {           

                                 $auditQuery = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAuditQuery($site)   

                                 $items = $list.get_Items()

                                 foreach ($item in $items)

                                 {

                                        $IsRecord = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records]::IsRecord($item)

                                        if ($IsRecord)

                                        {

                                               $auditQuery.RestrictToListItem($item)

                                               $auditResults = $site.Audit.GetEntries($auditQuery)

                                               foreach ($entry in $auditResults)

                                               {

                                                     $userId = $entry.UserId           

                                                     $userEntry = $web.AllUsers | Where {$_.ID -eq $userId}

                                                     $userLogin = $userEntry.LoginName

                                               }

                                               $declaredDate = [Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.RecordsRepository.Records]::RecordDeclarationDate($item)

                                               Write-Host $declaredDate $item.Name $userLogin

                                        }

                                 }

                           }

                    }

             }

       }

       $site.Dispose()

}
```

You can also execute PowerShell script from c#. Please! check the reference.

[PowerShell script from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)

**EDIT**

> 2. The possible scenario with CSOM.

Check below mention 2 references, first one is getting `_vti_ItemDeclaredRecord` and then you can retrieve audit log history and check on that timestamp who make that audit.

[retrieve `_vti_ItemDeclaredRecord`](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Check-whether-a-document-is-already-a-Record-or-Not-(IsRecord)-in-SharePoint-Office-365-programmatically-using-C-CSOM)

[audit log using CSOM](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fd628034-9d6d-4f98-afb8-1d0bd6926bd0/accessing-audit-logs-using-csom-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

*code to retrieve `_vti_ItemDeclaredRecord`*

```
    Records.IsRecord(file.Context, file.ListItemAllFields);

    string recordStatus = string.Empty;
    if (file.ListItemAllFields.Properties.FieldValues.ContainsKey("_vti_ItemHoldRecordStatus"))
    {
        switch (Convert.ToInt32(file.ListItemAllFields.Properties["_vti_ItemHoldRecordStatus"]))
        {
            case 0:
                recordStatus = "Normal Document";
                break;
            case 4353:
                recordStatus = "Hold";
                break;
            case 273:
                recordStatus = "Record";
                break;
            default:
                recordStatus = string.Empty;
                break;
        }
    }

    if (file.ListItemAllFields.Properties.FieldValues.ContainsKey("_vti_ItemDeclaredRecord"))
    {
        switch (Convert.ToDateTime(file.ListItemAllFields.Properties["_vti_ItemDeclaredRecord"]))
        {
            default:
                recordStatus = string.Empty;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not really an option as there is no CSOM only way to run that